# Поиск фрагмента текста

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Почему во фразе `frase = "Там было 6 603 408 человек"` по коду:

```
result=re.findall('(\d+\.*) человек',frase, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
```

находится только 408, а первые цифры - нет?

Да, они - увы! - разделены пробелом в тексте, который мне нужно "обрабатывать".

Comment: На [этом](https://regex101.com) сервисе можно по шагам пройтись и понять, как именно выполняется регулярное выражение и что вы забыли учесть.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Примеры:

```
In [54]: re.findall('(\d[\d\s\.]*) человек', "Там было 6 603 408 человек" , re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
Out[54]: ['6 603 408']

In [55]: re.findall('(\d[\d\s\.]*) человек', "Там было 6.603.408 человек" , re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
Out[55]: ['6.603.408']
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное :)

Comment: @AlexeiZhuravlev, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)